# What's the difference between Class<*> and Class<T>

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two way of writing  my functions as below

```
private fun createFragment(fragmentClass: Class<*>, fragmentArgs: Bundle?): Fragment {
    try {
        val fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance() as Fragment
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        return fragment
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(exception.message)
    }
}
```

And this

```
private fun <T>createFragment(fragmentClass: Class<T>, fragmentArgs: Bundle?): Fragment {
    try {
        val fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance() as Fragment
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        return fragment
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(exception.message)
    }
}
```

I don't know what's the different of making it `Class<*>` vs 'Class`. How do they differ from each other? Which is is better?

Note: I understand the  is done better using `reified` e.g. , without need to use `Class` at all. But I just want to understand without `reified`, what's the different between using `Class<*>` vs `Class<T>`

Comment: Does these codes compile with `fragmentClass.newInstance()` statement?!

Comment: Yes, it does. I copy the code out from a working code.

Comment: the first thing that came to my head that if you have 2 Class<T> type parameters, you can't enforce the same type on both with *, but you can with <T>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` is called [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections). You use it when you have to specify a generic type but don't care for what it is (maybe because you don't need it).

---

Since this question is not in a special way related to the `Class<T>` class, let me show you how it works with a simple example:

Consider this simple function that takes a `List` and prints it:

```
fun printList(l: List) { println(l) }
```

It won't compile with the following error:

> One type argument expected for interface `List<out E>`

I could fix it like this:

```
fun <T> printList(l: List<T>) { println(l) }
```

but this is tedious because I actually don't care for `T` and I don't need it.

Here comes the star-projection into play:

```
fun printList(l: List<*>) { println(l) }
```

This will compile, is short and concise.

---

So, in your particular example you should use `Class<*>` because you simply don't need `T`.

Comment: Good answer - addition: it's more or less functionally equivalent to Java's `?` wildcard.

Comment: @Moira Thx! It is a good addition since most Kotlin developers come from a Java background, but isn't `*` more equivilent to Java's rawtype? "Note: star-projections are very much like Java's raw types, but safe."

Answer (score 0):

Both resulted in the exact same decompiled Java code

```
private final Fragment createFragment(Class fragmentClass, Bundle fragmentArgs) {
  try {
     Object var10000 = fragmentClass.newInstance();
     if (var10000 == null) {
        throw new TypeCastException("null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.v4.app.Fragment");
     } else {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment)var10000;
        fragment.setArguments(fragmentArgs);
        return fragment;
     }
  } catch (Exception var4) {
     throw (Throwable)(new RuntimeException(var4.getMessage()));
  }
}
```

So they are the same. Like what @Willi Mentzel says, we should only use `Class<T>` if we need to use `T`. One example is as below (e.g. return the type of it), that we could get the exact same type

```
private fun <T>createFragmentX(fragmentClass: Class<T>, fragmentArgs: Bundle?): T {
    try {
        val fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance()
        (fragment as Fragment).arguments = fragmentArgs
        return fragment
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(exception.message)
    }
}
```